# Why is my JBoss wrapper application JVM restarted?

Tags: java, jboss, jvm

My OS version is Windows 7 64 bit and the JDK is 32 bit version. I started my JBoss Wrapper Application successfully, but after it ran for a while the JVM failed and restarted.

The message in the JVM dump log is:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 543672 bytes for Chunk::new
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (allocation.cpp:328), pid=5480, tid=4740
#
# JRE version: 7.0_05-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (23.1-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
```

I deploy 3 wrapper applications on my computer. Each of them set to a maximum JVM heap size of 700Mb.

Please help me review this problem. thanks. My questions are:

1. How can I know current JVM allocated size?
2. What is the reason for this problem?
3. How can fix it? Someone recommended me to use the 64 bit JDK. Is it necessary?

Comment: All , Sorry for forgetting some important info. I deploy 3 wrapper applications in my computer . Each of them set Max jvm heap size is 700Mb. Thanks

Comment: Yes, they are all contending for the same memory resources on your system.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `32-bit JDK`, the maximum heap size we can set and still have the `JVM start up is about 1.2 GB.For larger heaps, we need to run a 64-bit JDK.  To run  64-bit JDK, you’d also need a` 64-bit`operating system running on a server that has a`64-bit` CPU.

1. Downloaded the `JDK 64 bit version`
2. Set the JAVA_OPTS to

   ```
    JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
   ```

and refer this [link](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=4684c0510e2babffffffffb3f076c6e0ddca0?bug_id=7013538).

Also this is good article about [memory](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nativememory-linux/).

Comment: please see my comments. Does it matter with the multiple jvm run in same computer . thanks.

Comment: ok.but you are using jdk 32 bit version how its sufficient for you? In your error also clearly show as "Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS".

Comment: Do these three jvm instance use the one heap? Because I set each of them use about 700m max size memory.

Comment: I mean, Don't they each jvm runs in different process? I thought it supposed they aren't impacted each others for the issue of the max size in 32 jvm. because I thought each of them are set 700m not reach the allowed max size . thanks.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit JVM are limited to a 2GB heap maximum (`-Xmx`). In some operating systems, much less than that.

A 64-bit JVM will not have this limitation.

In Windows, you can follow your JVM's memory consumption with 
**Task Manager->Processes.**

Comment: please see my comments. Does it matter with the multiple jvm run in same computer . thanks.